# Changing the default boot option in the boot menu

Tags: linux

How do I change the boot options so that I can boot from USB?

[image: boot options screenshot]

Comment: If your BIOS doesn't let you, then you don't.

Comment: More information is required... What make and model PC? Can you not access the one-time boot menu? Can you not change the boot priority (Boot Option #1), etc?

Comment: i can change the options - eg the Boot Option #1 - but wich one is the correct one...?!

Comment: it is the following Notebook MEDION® AKOYA® E4254
http://www.computerbild.de/artikel/cb-Tests-Notebooks-Netbooks-Aldi-Notebook-Medion-Akoya-E4254-im-Test-21762503.html
https://www.pc-magazin.de/news/medion-akoya-e4254-test-aldi-laptop-schnaeppchen-check-lohnt-sich-3199491.html

Comment: helllo - just click the link above - then you see more infos and  datas - Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** Keep in mind you'll be navigating and adjusting settings with your *keyboard only*. This model of UEFI doesn't have mouse support.

#### Switching the boot priority

First, for simplicity, you may just want to disable Fast Boot with the option shown in the screenshot. Many guides recommend this step when booting from a USB(depending on your version of Windows). Use the arrow keys to go up to select `Fast Boot`, then hit `Enter` to select it and choose `Disabled` if available.

Next, go up to Boot Option #1 and hit `Enter`. You'll want to now select any option that has "USB" in the title. Then hit `F10` to save and quit. Since you may have multiple USB ports, you might need to do repeat this step a couple times, booting up, entering your firmware, and selecting another USB option if the first one didn't boot from the right place.

#### Tweaking additional options in case no USBs are working on boot

Along with disabling fast boot, you may need to change additional options to be able to load your USB drive.

**Legacy USB Support:** This option may be found in the `Main` section you view above.

**Legacy boot mode(instead of UEFI):** You may also need to find an option called `Boot Mode` and switch it to "CSM" or "Legacy" instead of "UEFI". This may also be in the `Main` section but have a look through all the sections for this since every version of UEFI can be quite different.

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DOFy8IP7Nt8) may help you to feel more comfortable viewing and changing the various options necessary to boot from USB. It shows a user adjusting the first of these two options.